# Installing ODEPACK on a Mac with C++ Code

Tags: macos, fortran, homebrew, lapack, blas

I used homebrew to install R on my mac.  My question is we have an example code that uses dlsode as a call, programmed in c++.  When I compile I get linker errors.  How would I properly link the library, and is the R package what I need to use ODEPACK calls?

The error-----

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "dlsode_(void (*)(int*, double*, double*, double*), int*, double*, double*, double*, int*, double*, double*, int*, int*, int*, double*, int*, int*, int*, void (*)(int, double, double*, int*, int*, double*, int*), int*)", referenced from:
      _main in test-38f452.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please tell us what linker errors you are getting during compile.

Comment: Please use some formatting.  Also show how you link with the library. It seems you do not link the library in at all.

Comment: Vladmir, I'm having trouble finding a way to install the library correctly for mac.